# JQuery - element exists in code but returns 0 when using .length()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have spent hours trying to figure out why the **$('#news-main-container').html(itemlist);** isn't working and found that when I use `alert($('[id="news-main-container"]').length);` it returns 0, implicating the element doesnt exist but I can see the element in the code when I inspect element.  The **itemlist** is alerting but it won't insert into **#news-main-container** because it thinks it doesn't exist.  Does anyone know what could cause this?

[image]

```
//get cached News JSON
function getNewsCache(){
        cache['news'] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('news'));
        var objCache = cache['news'].data;
        objCache = JSON.parse(objCache); //Parse string to json
        buildNewsList(objCache);                
}

//build HTML list of news items
function buildNewsList(objCache){
        var itemlist='';
        $.each(objCache, function(i, jd) {
            var newstitle = jd.title.rendered;
            var newsexcerpt = jd.excerpt.rendered;
            var newscontent = jd.content.rendered;
            var newsimageid = jd.featured_media;
            var thumbsrc = '';

            itemlist = itemlist+'<div class="content-news-box" id="newsclick" data-newscontent="'+newscontent+'" data-newstitle="'+newstitle+'"><div class="news-thumb-img"><img height="150px" src="'+thumbsrc+'"/></div><div class="news-title">'+newstitle+'</div><div class="news-excerpt">'+newsexcerpt+'<img height="40px" class="news-arrow-right" src="img/icon-arrow-right.png"/></div></div>';

        });
       alert(itemlist);
       alert($('[id="news-main-container"]').length);  //returns 0 but I can see it in the code!!
       $('#news-main-container').html(itemlist);  //WHY DOESNT THIS WORK?!?!?!
}

$("#load-news").click(function(event){
         $('#stage').html('');
         $('#stage').css('background','none');
         $("#stage").load("news.html");
        var data = {};  
        //get cache     
        cache['news'] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('news'));  
        getNewsCache();
});
```

Comment: Does anything else work? E.g. the `click` handler?

Comment: Do you create this element dynamically with Js? Does element show up when you run this inside Chrome console `$('#news-main-container')`. Is this Js code enclosed in `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Does `itemlist` actually contain anything? This behaviour may be caused by nothing being appended

Comment: try to navigate dom from parent element `#stage` or `document` if the target element is inserted dynamically

Comment: You've asked the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871884/jquery-html-method-not-working) two hours ago...

Comment: yes everything else works, the click event, the itemlist is alerted right before the .html() method and contains data. Yes it is enclosed within document ready.  #news-main-container is added dynamically with JS but I can see it in the code so it is there!

Comment: Could you post code where you add `#news-main-container` or best create codepen.

Comment: add `console.log($("#stage").html())` before  this `alert($('[id="news-main-container"]').length);` and see if the target element is there in console.

Comment: The target isn't there, it obviously hasn't loaded yet.  So why does it show in the console?  I use $("#stage").load("news.html"); to load this element and have amended the code above to show this.  Sorry I should have included it originally but thought it was irrelevant

Comment: Ok, I have re-arranged my code so that everything comes within $( "#stage" ).load( "news.html", function() { } and that works. Thanks @The_ehT, your suggestion got me there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-arranged my code so that everything comes within **$( "#stage" ).load( "news.html", function() { }** and that works. Thanks @The_ehT, your suggestion got me there!

Answer (score -2):

Most likely you run this code before DOM is rendered, so element doesn't exist at the runtime. Try enclosing your code in "document ready"

```
$(function(){
    // Your code
});
```